# can't convert undefined to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Update: I have added the fiddle. Please refer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fPVaJ/). use web console for error.

I am writing a code for traveling salesman problem. Here is the code :

```
var ind =[];      //values selected 
var cp =[];
var X;
var Y;
var tour = [];


// no values selected in the starting
for(j=0;j<friends_cnt;j++) {
  ind[j] = 0;
}


// distances at i,i infinity
for(i=0;i<friends_cnt;i++) {
  distance[i][i] = 9999999999999;
}

var k = 0;
var X = 0;

tour[k] =  X;
ind[X] = 1;


var i =1;
while(i<friends_cnt &&  ind[i] === 0) {
  var min = 9999999999999;

    // finding minimum of the undeleted values
    for(j=0;j<friends_cnt;j++) {
      if(ind[j] === 0) {
        if(distance[X][j] < min) {
          min = distance[X][j];
          Y = j;  // y is the min city
        }
      }
    }


    k = k+1;               // counter for the starting city
    tour[k] = Y;           //city added
    ind[Y] = 1;            

   X = Y;
   i++;
}

k = k+1;
tour[k] = tour[1];

for(var q=0;q<k+1;q++) {
  console.log(tour[q]);
}

});
});
```

now here whenever i run my program, it shows an error

`TypeError: can't convert undefined to object`

in the line

```
var min = 9999999999999;
```

My question is that is this because JavaScript cant handle large numbers or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's max number is 1.7976931348623157e+308 (aka the var `Number.MAX_VALUE`), so that shouldn't be an issue.

If you are trying to access an object of an object, it won't work.

You have `distance[X][j]`. That tries to access key `j` of `distance[X]`. To fix this, define `distance[X]` as an object:

```
distance[X] = [];
```

Other example:

```
var distance = [];

distance[i]
//undefined;

distance[i][i]
//syntax error

distance[i] = [];

distance[i][i]
//undefined;
```

For 2D arrays, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript) question.

Comment: Rest of the code runs fine. The problem comes when i try to play with the data  ie distance[][].

Comment: Added to answer - it's outlined in another question. Also, min and max Javascript integers are respectively `Number.MIN_VALUE` and `Number.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for minimum number 
`var min = int.MinValue`
For max number
`var max = int.MaxValue`

**Edited**
Refer [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE)

```
Number.Max_Value  
Number.Min_Value
```

**UPDATED**
If you see your code you have filled the `ind[]` from `0`

```
for(j=0;j<friends_cnt;j++) {
  ind[j] = 0;
}
```

and in your while condition you have set value of `i` from `1`. So for the last element it may be throwing error

Comment: will it add minimum value to variable min or a large number. I want large number

Comment: it says int is not defined.

Comment: `var min = 9999999999999;` works fine and is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually here:

```
distance[i][i] = 9999999999999;
```

If `distance` is `undefined` or an empty array, that statement will fail. This should fix it:

```
var distance = []; // <-- this is missing from the top of your code

// ...

if (!distance[i]) {
    distance[i] = [];
}
distance[i][i] = 9999999999999;
```